# Installed Jenkins on a Debian Server and unable to connect on any port

Tags: linux, debian, debian-squeeze, jenkins

I installed Jenkins on a Debian server and everything seems to have worked fine.

It says Jenkins is running and I am able to start and stop it using (/etc/init.d/jenkins start).

However I am unable to pull it up on a browser using any port for example 8080 or some other port as it says unable to connect.

What can I do to trouble shoot this further? I was thinking that the port may have been blocked but then I use to have another application that ran fine on port 8080 (since uninstalled)

Thanks

Comment: "_It says Jenkins is running and I am unable to start and stop it using (/etc/init.d/jenkins start)._" Is that an typo, and you are able to start it, or is there an error message when you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins is probably configured to listen on 127.0.0.1 by default, instead of your public interface.  To check this, run: `netstat -anp | grep 8080'`. If the line that comes up shows `127.0.0.1:8080` you need to adjust the address Jenkins listens on.  You can find more info on that at https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Starting+and+Accessing+Jenkins

Comment: nothing shows up when I try that line

Comment: Are you sure Jenkins is even running? `ps aux | grep -i java` or 'netstat -anp | grep -i java`.  Make sure you are running these commands as root.

Comment: root     17787  0.0  0.0   7672   888 pts/0    S+   02:25   0:00 grep -i java